# What directive should I use to decode this date string with datetime.strptime?

Tags: python, datetime

I have been using the following directive to decode this string.

```
datetime.strptime('2021-07-09T21:01:49.926811Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')
```

But I get this error message:

> ValueError: time data '2021-07-09T21:01:49.926811Z' does not match
> format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z'

What is the right format ?

Comment: Please try without the final "%".

Comment: and please stop [duplicating your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68509968/10197418). You can always edit them and they can be reopened if appropriate.